# Problem with Gazebo after update

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I updated gazebo today (from apt (ubuntu 12.04)) and when i load one of my robots to gazebo all of the robot parts appear in random places.

URDF for my robot is located in : https://github.com/RCPRG-ros-pkg/lwr_robot/tree/electric/lwr_defs

[image: image description]

After updating to svn trunk it works much better.
But that not solve all of my problems, the second robot link appear translated from its base. It looks like a problem with chaining of fixed links. When i remove the world link and world to world_link joint the offset disappear.
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42211/problem-with-gazebo-after-update./) by [konradb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/2207/konradb3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

---

update

Ok, there was [another issue](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5547), thanks konradb3 for the patch!  The new release simulator_gazebo 1.6.16 deb is out.

---

Thanks for posting the model, I was able to test it and found a transform bug when I tried to tweak the urdf2gazebo parser.  It's fixed in trunk.  I'll make a release (simulator_gazebo 1.6.14) this weekend.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [konradb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/2207/konradb3/) on 2012-08-24**:
I checked the svn trunk and it works much better but some problems still remains.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-24**:
great.  can you list out the problems or ticket them on trac (https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues?status=new&status=open)?  thanks!

**Comment by [konradb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/2207/konradb3/) on 2012-08-24**:
Question updated ...

**Comment by [shart115](https://answers.ros.org/users/1531/shart115/) on 2012-08-27**:
i'm seeing a similar problem with the Robonaut2 simulator since the update as well.

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2012-08-27**:
Problem also exists with the youBot URDF from https://github.com/youbot/youbot-ros-pkg

**Comment by [bsatzinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/822/bsatzinger/) on 2012-08-27**:
I'm seeing similar problems as well. Is there documentation somewhere on the best way to checkout simulator_gazebo from svn trunk and replace the existing version I got from apt-get without goofing everything up?

**Comment by [shart115](https://answers.ros.org/users/1531/shart115/) on 2012-08-28**:
any updates on this fix?  It is somewhat unclear whether the trunk fixes this issue (and it doesnt look like 1.6.14 has been released yet...

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-28**:
just released 1.6.14 yesterday, deb should be out in a day or two.  Is the second picture in your original question correct?  That's what I see as well.  Is there suppose to be a gap between calib_lwr_arm_base_link and lwr_arm_1_link as shown?  Also, you mentioned that something else is broken?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-28**:
If possible, can you post a picture of what the model should look like?  thanks.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-31**:
can someone confirm that simulator_gazebo 1.6.14 fixes the issue?